# Why, in simple terms, is Cohen's D not affected by sample size but a T-Test is?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cohens-d

Why, in simple terms, is Cohen's D not affected by sample size but a T-Test is? I don't really understand and tbh am struggling to tell the difference between the two at all.

Comment: Are you asking for whether the definitions of Cohen's $d$ and the $t$-statistic contain the sample sizes as functional terms, or why the quantities are defined that way?

Comment: Cohen's *d* is a property (or assumed property, or corresponding estimate of that property) of a *population.*  To a small extent estimates of *d* can be affected by sample size, just as any parameter estimates might be.

Comment: I've heard that one of the advantages to cohen's d is that its result isn't affected by population size, whereas a T-Test result is affected by that. I don't understand why, though. A T-Test result changes with sample size due to how variation changes in a sample is lowered as it increases, right? And yet Cohen's d, which also involves variation, is immune to this change?

Comment: The "variation" involved in $d$ is the *population* standard deviation.  This remains the same no matter what the sample size might be.  The variation in a t-test is the *sampling variation* of the t statistic.  Provided the population has a finite variance, the t-test variation shrinks to zero as the sample size increases.

Answer (score 3):

**Standardized mean difference** is the raw effect size (ie difference of the means of two populations) divided by the standard deviation of the population (in the simple case when both population have the same deviation). It is a way to express the effect size in a dimensionless way.

The standardized mean difference, is a property of the populations. It has not to do with the sample size and is *not* influenced by the sample size.

**Cohen's $\bf d$** is a statistic that estimates the standardized mean difference.

For Cohen's $d$, which is a statistic computed with a sample, there will be an influence of the sample size on the distribution of the statistic. This difference is that for increasing sample size the Cohen's $d$ will be more close to the standardized mean difference (but the expectation value of Cohen's $d$ will not be affected by the sample size).

**The t-statistic** is the observed effect size divided by the standard error of the observed effect size. This error becomes smaller for larger samples, and the t-statistic will be larger for smaller samples (provided the effect size is non-zero).

---

#### Example

When we estimate the difference in the means of two populations, $\mu_2- \mu _1$, then we have the following expressions for the standard mean difference, Cohen's $d$, and the t-statistic.

**Standardized mean difference** is a property of the populations and independent from $n$ and just the difference in the (true) population means divided by the (true) standard deviation of the populations (more complex formula's exist when the population's standard deviations are unequal)

$$SMD = \frac{\mu_2- \mu_1}{\sigma}$$

Below is an example for two Gaussian distributed populations. The effect size is in this case two standard deviations so $SMD=2$.

[image: standardized mean difference]

**Cohen's $\bf d$** is a statistic that estimates the standardized mean difference from the sample in which case you have

$${d} = \frac{\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2}{s}$$

with the sample means $\bar{x}_i$, and $s$ the estimate of the distribution standard deviations (for the simple case that the deviations are assumed to be equal, $s$ is the pooled standard deviation).

**The t-statistic**

$$t =  \frac{\bar{x}_2-\bar{x}_1}{S.E.(\bar{x}_2-\bar{x}_1)} = \frac{\bar{x}_2-\bar{x}_1}{s \cdot \sqrt{2/n}} = \sqrt{n/2} d
$$

This standard error of the difference between the sample means, $S.E.(\bar{x}_2-\bar{x}_1) = s \cdot \sqrt{2/n}$, scales with the sample size and becomes smaller for larger samples.

---

See below an example of the distribution of ${d}$ and $t$ for different sample sizes when the true standardized effect size is $SMD=0.1$. (the distributions will be non-central t-distributions)

[image: distribution]

For a given effect size, when ${n}$ increases then the t-statistic can become very high. This is because the error of the observed effect size becomes smaller.

On the other hand, Cohen's $d$, will approach the real effect size (standardized mean difference) and does not become bigger for increasing sample size $n$.

Even very small effect sizes (in terms of the standardized mean difference) can result in a large t-statistic as long as $\sqrt{n}$ (the sample size) is large enough.

Comment: The terminology here is potentially confusing, because Cohen defined "effect size" to be the difference in means (which he termed the "raw effect size") divided by the population SD.  Thus, it appears at least two distinctions must be made as a clear as possible: (1) that between the "raw" and standardized effect sizes and (2) that between population values and estimates.  Reference: *Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences,* 2nd Ed. (1988), section 2.2.

Comment: yes this is confusing. Usually isn't it the pooled standard deviation?

Answer (score 0):

Effect size shouldn't be affected (at least not the way p-values go to zero!), it just gets more precise. Usually one divides by the pooled std in practice since we can't calculate the true std from the population.

[image]

### [image]

Code:

```
"""
Effect size = is a quantative measure of the strength of a phenomenon. Effect size emphasizes the size of the difference
    or relationship. e.g. the distance between the two means of two hyptoehsis H0, H1 (if they were Gaussian distributions).

Cohen’s d measures the difference between the mean from two Gaussian-distributed variables.
It is a standard score that summarizes the difference in terms of the number of standard deviations.
Because the score is standardized, there is a table for the interpretation of the result, summarized as:
    - Small Effect Size: d=0.20
    - Medium Effect Size: d=0.50
    - Large Effect Size: d=0.80

note:
    - you usually look up the effect size in you application/field (todo why)
    - depends on statistical test/hypothesis decision procedure (e.g. t-test, ANOVA, etc.).
    - large is good if you get a large effect size.
    - Q: why can't we control the effect size? (todo why) I think it's just a function of field/nature & your hypothesis
    - Q: how does it relate to number of samples? does it lead to the issues CIs lead e.g. Pf -> 1 Pm->0?
    - Courtney says, if the effect size is large, then a smaler sample size is needed. My guess is that n (sample size)
    should not affect negatively the effect size.
    - if effect size is small, then a larger sample size is needed (Courney says) (todo: why?)

ref:
    - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LVD9oLg1A0&list=PLljPCllSdtzWop4iDNyyuZ2NZokOHeQqm&index=6
    - https://machinelearningmastery.com/effect-size-measures-in-python/


todo: later
    Two other popular methods for quantifying the difference effect size are:

    Odds Ratio. Measures the odds of an outcome occurring from one treatment compared to another.
    Relative Risk Ratio. Measures the probabilities of an outcome occurring from one treatment compared to another.
"""


# function to calculate Cohen's d for independent samples
def _cohen_d(d1, d2):
    """
    Compute Cohen's d for independent samples.

    ref:
        - from: https://machinelearningmastery.com/effect-size-measures-in-python/
```

## seed random number generator

seed(1)

## prepare data

data1 = 10 * randn(10000) + 60
data2 = 10 * randn(10000) + 55

## calculate cohen's d

d = cohend(data1, data2)
print('Cohens d: %.3f' % d)

```
    Note:
        -   ddof : int, optional
            Means Delta Degrees of Freedom.  The divisor used in calculations
            is ``N - ddof``, where ``N`` represents the number of elements.
            By default `ddof` is zero.
    """
    # calculate the Cohen's d between two samples
    from numpy.random import randn
    from numpy.random import seed
    from numpy import mean
    from numpy import var
    from math import sqrt

    # calculate the size of samples
    n1, n2 = len(d1), len(d2)
    # calculate the variance of the samples
    v1, v2 = var(d1, ddof=1), var(d2, ddof=1)
    # calculate the pooled standard deviation
    s = sqrt(((n1 - 1) * v1 + (n2 - 1) * v2) / (n1 + n2 - 2))
    # calculate the means of the samples
    u1, u2 = mean(d1), mean(d2)
    # calculate the effect size
    cohen_d: float = (u1 - u2) / s
    return cohen_d


def compute_effect_size_t_test_cohens_d(group1: iter, group2: iter) -> tuple[float, float]:
    """
    Compute effect size for a t-test (Cohen's d). The distance in pooled std between the two means.

    Note:
        - The Cohen’s d calculation is not provided in Python; we can calculate it manually. ref: https://machinelearningmastery.com/effect-size-measures-in-python/
        -
    """
    from numpy import mean
    # calculate the pooled standard deviation
    pooled_std: float = compute_pooled_std_two_groups(group1, group2)
    # calculate the means of the samples
    u1, u2 = mean(group1), mean(group2)
    # calculate the effect size
    cohen_d: float = (u1 - u2) / pooled_std
    return cohen_d, pooled_std


def compute_pooled_std_two_groups(group1: iter, group2: iter, ddof: int = 1) -> float:
    """
    Compute pooled std for two groups.

    ref:
        - https://machinelearningmastery.com/effect-size-measures-in-python/
    """
    import numpy as np
    pooled_std: float = np.sqrt((np.std(group1, ddof=ddof) ** 2 + np.std(group2, ddof=ddof) ** 2) / 2)
    return pooled_std


def get_standardized_acceptable_difference(eps: float, group1: iter, group2: iter) -> float:
    """
    Get standardized acceptable difference/eps/epsilon. Recommended use: compare with effect size to see if your effect size is
    in the range of acceptable difference. e.g. if effect size is "low" but it's close to the acceptable difference,
    then there is an argument to accept your hypothesis (reject the null) i.e. there is a noticeable difference.
    """
    # calculate the pooled standard deviation
    pooled_std: float = compute_pooled_std_two_groups(group1, group2)
    # calculate the effect size
    standardized_acceptable_difference: float = eps / pooled_std
    return standardized_acceptable_difference


# - decicion procedures

def print_interpretation_of_cohends_d_decision_procedure(d: float):
    """ Print interpretation of Cohen's d decision procedure. """
    print(
        f'Decision: (is there a minimal difference between the means of two groups or a minimal relationship between two variables?)'
        f'(please note the sign of {d=})')
    d: float = abs(d)
    if d < 0.35:
        print(f"Small Effect Size: d~0.20, {d < 0.35=}, {d=}")
    elif 0.35 <= d < 0.65:
        print(f"Medium Effect Size: d~0.50, {0.35 <= d < 0.65=}, {d=}")
    elif d >= 0.65:
        print(f"Large Effect Size: d~0.80, {d >= 0.65=}, {d=}")
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unexpected value for d: {d}")


def decision_based_on_effect_size_and_standardized_acceptable_difference(
        effect_size: float,
        standardized_acceptable_difference: float) -> bool:
    """
    Function that accepts or rejects null hypothesis based on effect size and accepted without using confidence intervals.
    i.e. just compares the if the effect size is larger than the standardized acceptable difference.
    Logic/Justification: if people accept papers/knowledge based on the (standardized) acceptable difference then we
    can point out our difference is within that range and therefore we can "accept" our hypothesis (reject the null).

    Similar to the CIs test & CI tests are recommended to be also done

    Note:
        - eps - 1% or 2% based on ywx's suggestion (common acceptance for new method is SOTA in CVPR like papers).
    """
    effect_size: float = abs(effect_size)
    if effect_size >= standardized_acceptable_difference:
        print(f"H1 (Reject the null hypothesis, Effect size is larger than the standardized acceptable difference): "
              f"{effect_size >= standardized_acceptable_difference=}")
    else:
        print(f"H0 (Accept the null hypothesis, Effect size is smaller than the standardized acceptable difference): "
              f"{effect_size < standardized_acceptable_difference=}")
    return effect_size >= standardized_acceptable_difference  # True if H1 else False H0


# - tests

def my_test_using_stds_from_real_expts_():
    """
    This is the tutorial for doing hypothesis testing for small and large samples.
        - for small samples you can use everything including the p-value and eps = 0
        - for large samples use everything except the p-value and eps=0 for CIs
    """
    import numpy as np

    # Example data
    std_m = 0.061377
    std_u = 0.085221
    N = 100
    N_m = N
    N_u = N
    mu_m = 0.855
    mu_u = 0.893
    group1 = np.random.normal(mu_m, std_m, N_m)
    group2 = np.random.normal(mu_u, std_u, N_u)
    print(f'{std_m=}')
    print(f'{std_u=}')
    print(f'{N_m=}')
    print(f'{N_u=}')
    print(f'{mu_m=}')
    print(f'{mu_u=}')

    # Perform t-test
    from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
    t_stat, p_value = ttest_ind(group1, group2)

    # Compute Cohen's d
    print('---- effect size analysis ----')
    cohen_d, pooled_std = compute_effect_size_t_test_cohens_d(group1, group2)
    _cohen_d_val: float = _cohen_d(group1, group2)

    print("Cohen's d:", cohen_d)
    print("_cohen_d:", _cohen_d_val)


    # Compare with acceptable difference/epsilon
    acceptable_difference1: float = 0.01  # 1% difference/epsilon
    acceptable_difference2: float = 0.02  # 2% difference/epsilon
    standardized_acceptable_difference1: float = get_standardized_acceptable_difference(acceptable_difference1, group1,
                                                                                        group2)
    standardized_acceptable_difference2: float = get_standardized_acceptable_difference(acceptable_difference2, group1,
                                                                                        group2)
    # print(f'{acceptable_difference1=}')
    # print(f'{acceptable_difference2=}')
    print(f'{standardized_acceptable_difference1=}')
    print(f'{standardized_acceptable_difference2=}')
    decision_based_on_effect_size_and_standardized_acceptable_difference(cohen_d, standardized_acceptable_difference1)
    decision_based_on_effect_size_and_standardized_acceptable_difference(cohen_d, standardized_acceptable_difference2)
    print_interpretation_of_cohends_d_decision_procedure(cohen_d)

    # CIs/Confidence Intervals
    print('---- CIs/Confidence Intervals ----')
    from uutils.stats_uu.ci_uu import mean_confidence_interval, decision_based_on_acceptable_difference_cis
    m1, ci1 = mean_confidence_interval(group1)
    m2, ci2 = mean_confidence_interval(group2)
    decision_based_on_acceptable_difference_cis((m1, ci1), (m2, ci2), 0.0)
    decision_based_on_acceptable_difference_cis((m1, ci1), (m2, ci2), acceptable_difference1)
    decision_based_on_acceptable_difference_cis((m1, ci1), (m2, ci2), acceptable_difference2)

    # Print p-value
    print('---- p-value analysis ----')
    print("p-value: ", p_value)
    alpha: float = 0.01  # significance level
    from uutils.stats_uu.p_values_uu.t_test_uu import decision_procedure_based_on_statistically_significance
    decision_procedure_based_on_statistically_significance(p_value, alpha)

    # Print Power P_d (probability of detection, rejecting null if null is false)
    print('---- Power analysis P_d (probability of detection, rejecting null if null is false) ----')
    from uutils.stats_uu.power import _compute_power_ttest
    power: float = _compute_power_ttest(cohen_d, N, alpha)
    # from uutils.stats_uu.power import compute_power_posthoc_t_test
    # power2: float = compute_power_posthoc_t_test(cohen_d, N, alpha)
    from uutils.stats_uu.power import _compute_power_ttest
    power2: float = _compute_power_ttest(cohen_d, N, alpha)
    from uutils.stats_uu.power import _compute_power_ttest2
    # power3: float = _compute_power_ttest2(cohen_d, N, alpha)
    print(f'{power=}')
    print(f'{power2=}')
    # print(f'{power3=}')

    from uutils.stats_uu.power import print_interpretation_of_power
    print_interpretation_of_power(power)

    # - guess number of samples
    # print()
    # print('---- estimated number samples needed to get power ----')
    # print(f'true N used {N=}')
    # from uutils.stats_uu.power import get_estimated_number_of_samples_needed_to_reach_certain_power
    # N_estimated: float = get_estimated_number_of_samples_needed_to_reach_certain_power(cohen_d, alpha, power)
    # print(f'N_estimated {N_estimated=}')
    # print('(if gives numerical error ignore)')

def effect_size_depedence_on_N_test_():
    """
    This tests if effect size cohen's d depedence on N.

    Anser:
        - yes it does but not in the way it affects p-values & CIs. Since it measures a distance between two means --
        it gets better as N -> infinity and it's noisier for small N.

    Answer from SO:
    Estimate of Cohen's d: when we estimate Cohen's d from a sample then there will be some influence on the
    distribution. For increasing sample size the estimates will be more precise, but the expectation value of the
    estimate will not differ as a function of the sample size.

    ref:
        - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/550026/why-in-simple-terms-is-cohens-d-not-affected-by-sample-size-but-a-t-test-is?rq=1#:~:text=Cohen's%20d%20is%20the%20effect,influenced%20by%20the%20sample%20size.
    """
    import numpy as np

    # Example data
    std_m = 0.061377
    std_u = 0.085221
    N = 100
    N_m = N
    N_u = N
    mu_m = 0.855
    mu_u = 0.893
    group1 = np.random.normal(mu_m, std_m, N_m)
    group2 = np.random.normal(mu_u, std_u, N_u)
    print(f'{std_m=}')
    print(f'{std_u=}')
    print(f'{N_m=}')
    print(f'{N_u=}')
    print(f'{mu_m=}')
    print(f'{mu_u=}')

    # -
    ns: list[int] = [2, 10, 15, 30, 50, 75, 100, 150, 300, 500, 1000, 5_000, 10_000]
    effect_sizes: list[float] = []
    for n in ns:
        group2 = np.random.normal(mu_m, std_m, N_m)
        group1 = np.random.normal(mu_u, std_u, N_u)
        # - effect size
        cohen_d, pooled_std = compute_effect_size_t_test_cohens_d(group1, group2)
        _cohen_d_val: float = _cohen_d(group1, group2)
        print("Cohen's d:", cohen_d)
        print("_cohen_d:", _cohen_d_val)
        # - append
        effect_sizes.append(cohen_d)
    # - plot it
    from uutils.plot import plot
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plot(ns, effect_sizes, title='Effect size dependence on N', xlabel='N', ylabel='Cohen\'s d')
    plt.axhline(y=0.2, color='r', linestyle='-', label='0.2 (small)')
    plt.axhline(y=0.5, color='b', linestyle='-', label='0.5 (medium)')
    plt.axhline(y=0.8, color='g', linestyle='-', label='0.8 (large)')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

# - run it

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    start = time.time()
    # - run it
    # my_test_using_stds_from_real_expts_()
    effect_size_depedence_on_N_test_()
    # - Done
    from uutils import report_times

    print(f"\nSuccess Done!: {report_times(start)}\a")
```